# Sympy parse_expr takes a long time

Tags: python, out-of-memory, sympy

I am running a code that takes different inputs (generated by another code) as strings and I need to turn them into sympy expressions. I use `from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr` and it works well, however sometimes I get really big numbers (which are wrong expressions), but i can't check beforehand, as they come as strings and when I run parse_expr on them it takes forever. One such example is below:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
eq = "tan(sin(7.10414690881377e-30370322717341*x0) - 9183346819072.0)"
parse_expr(eq)
```

Again, in the actual code I don't know `eq` before hand. Is there an easy way to avoid this. For example to set a time limit on parse_expr? Or to set a limit on the maximum value allowed for a parameter in `eq`?

Comment: This is very slow for me on master and with sympy 1.6. It's trying to compute `Rational(710414690881377, 10**30370322717355)`. This is a bug that should be reported https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: No idea why, but I'm also running SymPy 1.6 and can run the code snippet in ~0.06 seconds. However, t just halts on @OscarBenjamin's one. To set timeouts on a single threaded application, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call). You could also use regex to check if there are more than, say, 5 digits in a row before a `.` or after an `e`.

Comment: I even get stuck on `parse_expr("7.14e-30370322")`, however `parse_expr("7.14e-3037032")` seems reasonably fast. Also sympy 1.6